# Why does receiving an Intent calls onPause()

Tags: android, android-intent, onpause

According to [Android's Activity lifecyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle), method Activity.onPause() is called only if another activity calls into the foreground. My application has only one activity which is itself set with android:launchMode="singleTask".

According to the stackstrace below receiving a new Intent triggers Activity.onPause().

**Can anyone explain why ?**

**Stacktrace:**

```
android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:3877)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1191)
android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:1736)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:1746)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:117)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:982)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is expected. I looked at the Android source code (v2.3.7) and before receiving an Intent the activity is paused.